# Downloaded Json Contains Null value and app Crash ios swift

Tags: ios, swift3

i am working an app in which data is downloaded from server in JSON format. but if Image value is nill then app crashed. i also set a default picture but cursor did not enter in else statement. Kindly guide me how i do my task correctly. Here is my code

```
func downloadUsersData(){

    let email = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userEmail")

    var urlString = "http://nexusvision.net/zeroone/selectuserbasic.php"
    urlString.append("?")
    urlString.append("id=\(email!)")

    print("This is URL : \(urlString)")

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

        }

        let data = data

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        print("all Countary responseString = \(responseString)")

        let responseData = responseString


        do {

            let jsonValue = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            print("This is Json : \(jsonValue.value(forKey: "product"))")

            if let profile = jsonValue.value(forKey: "product") as? NSArray
            {
                for profileData in profile{

                    if let dict = profileData as? NSDictionary{

                        if let firstName = dict.value(forKey: "firstname"){

                            print("Name is : \(firstName)")

                            self.defaults.set(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
                        }

                        if let lastName = dict.value(forKey: "lastname"){

                            print("Last Name : \(lastName)")
                            self.defaults.set(lastName, forKey: "lastName")

                        }

                        if let imageData = dict.value(forKey: "picture")    {

                            print("This is Image Json: \(imageData)")


                            let convertToImage = imageData

                            let decodedData : NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: convertToImage as! String, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!

                            let decodedimage: UIImage = UIImage(data: decodedData as Data)!


                            print("Thats Decoded : \(decodedimage)")

                            self.profilePicImageShow.image = decodedimage

                        }

                        else{

                            self.profilePicImageShow.image = UIImage(named: "Empty")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Every time you say `!` that means _crash me_. You say it 8 times. And you are surprised that you are crashing?

Comment: Don't force unwrap optionals unless you are 100% certain they contain a value.

Comment: i want to use else statement if JSON contains null value.

Comment: if i use ? instead of ! , then Xcode say set ? to ! .

Answer (score 0):

Technically, key "picture" is not nil, its empty string according to the JSON response. So when you execute the code, it will go into the if statement and finally crash at 
`let decodedimage: UIImage = UIImage(data: decodedData as Data)!` as `decodedData` is nil.

**Answer:**
Modify the your if statement as below

```
if let imageData = dict.value(forKey: "picture"), (imageData as! String) != ""   {
```

This should fix your crash problem.

Comment: When i use this it shows error like this,
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x102bf8918) to 'NSString' (0x101a7ec60).

Comment: This picture is downloaded as Base64 and then decoded

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if let imageData = dict.value(forKey: "picture") {
    print("This is Image Json: \(imageData)")
    let convertToImage = imageData
    let decodedData : NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: convertToImage as! String, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let decodedimage: UIImage = UIImage(data: decodedData as Data)!
    print("Thats Decoded : \(decodedimage)")
    self.profilePicImageShow.image = decodedimage
} else {
    self.profilePicImageShow.image = UIImage(named: "Empty")
}
```

with

```
let imageData = dict["picture"] as? NSData ?? UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Empty")!, 1.0)
self.profilePicImageShow.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

Also, make sure that the key "picture" actually contains nil

Answer (score 0):

You could add `guard` statements as follow:

```
guard let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: convertToImage as! String, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
   return
}


guard let decodedimage: UIImage = UIImage(data: decodedData as Data) else {
   return
}
```

Since you are forcing an unwrap, if it fails to create an image from the data, your app will crash.

As a side note, you could use [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [this](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper), those are really great libs to work with `HTTP` Requests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'll get URL from JSON and then download image with URL; So if url is nil then I'll add dummy image else I'll download Image from URL. Here is My Stuff :

```
var news = respone.result.value as! Dictionary<String,Any>
if let result:NSArray = news["stories"] as? NSArray
{
    for i in 0..<result.count
    {
        let str = (((result[i] as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "ximg") as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "ipath") as? String)

        if str == nil
        {
            self.news_url.append("nil")
        }
        else
        {
            self.news_url.append(str!)
        }
    }
}
self.tableview.reloadData()
```